# Transparent home page for firefox

Tags: mac, firefox, transparency

How can I make the default page of Firefox for Mac transparent so that one can see everything that is behind it?

Comment: Can you please elaborate, what do you mean by "so one can see everything that is behind" do you mean you want it transparent so the user can see the desktop?

Comment: yes, exactly! or even better, all the windows that are behind firefox's window

Comment: Don't start Firefox, and then say you did. It will be fully transparent, and you'll see everything behind it.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Don't you mean *translucent*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Afloat](http://infinite-labs.net/afloat/) is what you're looking for. This app has many different features for window management. The included [user guide](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3777028/A%20Guide%20to%20Afloat.pdf) has all of the features. Including:

> Transparency
>   lets you see through a window.

```
menu:             keyboard:        mouse:           macbooks:
Window >          ⌃⌘ + page up     ⌃⌘ + scroll up   ⌃⌘ + scroll up
Transparency      or pagedown      or down with     or down with
                                   the wheel.       two fingers.
```

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for [SetAlphaValue](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/16577/setalphavalue) or [WindowShade X](http://unsanity.com/haxies/wsx).

SetAlphaValue especially seems to have an option for "AlpahValue for windows with title", with which you might be able to render Firefox transparent just for the home page.

<sup>(Sorry, don't have a Mac to try this on)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Windows you can make applications transparent with [Pitaschio](http://pitaschio.ara3.net/).  It's more of an on-the-fly setting, so you would just make the windows transparent when needed. Here's a Firefox tutorial I found on google: http://userlogos.org/book/export/html/12170

Comment: No, they’re on Mac (as stated in the question).

Comment: yes, for mac, although the idea seems exactly what i need

Comment: He added the OS later. Thanks for the downvotes though.